# Laravel blade templating yield not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a `layouts/app.blade.php` view where I yield a content section.

layouts/app.blade.php

```
@yield('content')
```

adminpanel/adminpanel.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            @yield('sidebar')
        </div>

        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                @yield('page-content')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

adminpanel/sidebar.blade.php

```
@extends('adminpanel.adminpanel')

@section('sidebar')
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
            <a href="#">
                Profile
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">News</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
@endsection
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

When I type something in the `adminpanel/adminpanel.blade.php` view it works but the yielding of partials doesn't work.

Comment: Which view are you initializing/rendering?

Comment: In my controller I do `return view('adminpanel/adminpanel');`

Comment: are you returning `adminpanel.sidebar` as a view from a controller? because that would be what you would have to do as the sidebar template extends the adminpanel template ... the other template isn't "including" the sidebar, it is not a "partial"  ... so you have this kinda backwards from adminpanel to sidebar

Comment: @lagbox No I am not returning adminpanel.sidebar I am returning adminpanel.adminpanel. The sidebar is just, or should be a part of the adminpanel. I'll probably return the sidebar on multiple pages and I don't want to be build the sidebar on every view.

Comment: When you load `adminpanel.adminpanel` the sidebar is not actually loaded or referenced anywhere. You need to somehow include it in the admin panel view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are returning the "adminpanel/adminpanel", then you must include the sidebar from the admin-panel, not "yield" something for what you don't have the contents.

```
@include('adminpanel.sidebar')
```

instead of

```
@yield('page-content')
```

and then in your sidebar, remove all blade directives because they are no longer needed.

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">
            Profile
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can also write `@include('adminpanel.sidebar');`

Comment: Definitely, that's more blade-ish

Answer (score 2):

try include
**adminpanel/adminpanel.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            @include('adminpanel.sidebar')
        </div>

        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                @yield('page-content')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```